# How to use match against in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, match

```
TABLE ITEMS: (id, name)
1| chicken
2| potato
```

QUERY:

```
select * from items where match(name) against('tato');
```

An empty set is being returned. Have I miss understood how match against works ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

```
SELECT * FROM items
WHERE INSTR(name, 'tato') > 0
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM items
WHERE name LIKE '%tato'
```

Syntax you're using seems correct; do you have fulltext enabled on that field?

```
ALTER TABLE items ADD FULLTEXT(name);
```

Comment: This won't use any indexes, and will do a full table scan.  On any large table this approach will not work.

Comment: @KenMazaika: OP did not talk about "large tables"... Anyway, do you have some better idea?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think FULLTEXT indices support partial word matches.  For something like this you're better off using one of the constructions described by Marco.

Comment: That is correct, unless you use special operators to change the behaviour of MATCH AGAINST.  MATCH AGAINST can also do some weird things that may not be what you expect.  For example, it ignores any defined stop words and words that occur frequently in your DB.  It also ignores words which don't meet the ft_min_word_len system variable, whatever that is set to.  Because of these reasons, I strongly recommend taking Marco's suggestion and use INSTR or LIKE instead (though I would use LIKE '%tato%' just in case you want tato occurring anywhere in the string, and not just at the end).