# How to use MYSQL indexes in python 2.7 MySQLdb

Tags: python, mysql, sql, python-2.7, mysql-python

```
indie = '''CREATE FULLTEXT yay ON panda (Question, Answer);'''
cursor.execute(indie)
```

I already have a connection to the server, database and table and it all works, but for some reason it won't create the yay index on the columns Question and Answer in table panda.
I get the error:

```
_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'yay ON panda (Question, Answer)' at line 1")
```

I have checked most ways of fixing this but just don't understand. can anyone help?

Comment: The syntax of the query is incorrect, have you actual tested your query with a MySQL client ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your SQL syntax is incorrect, it should be

```
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX yay ON panda (Question, Answer);
```

See MySQL [reference manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html) for more details.

Comment: It works but now my MATCH...AGAINST  argument is throwing the error:

Comment: `_mysql_exception.OperationalError: (1191, "Can't find FULLTEXT index matching the column list")`

Comment: Don't worry. The answer at: <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9136238/how-to-use-match-against-in-mysql> fixed it